# Calling a JSP script and php script from html form action

Tags: php, jsp, forms, http-post

I have a form on a page that needs to call a php script on my website's server (it's below web root), and it also needs to call an external jsp script hosted on another website's server. I know I can't just put two items into the `<form action="..."` but I can't figure out a way to get this done. Both scripts need to receive the variables submitted by the form.

Edit: I've made a mistake here. I'm sorry, but I thought it was javascript, and it's actually JSP. I've modified my post to fix all the places where I mentioned javascript.

Answer (score 0):

you can add `onclick` event handler to the submit button, and include there all the javascript you need to perform **before** submission.

hope that helps.

**UPDATE:**

after you modified your question i realise you want to post to 2 server endpoints from the same client / webpage at the same time.

in this case i suggest you to:

1. not using a `<form>`
2. include `jQuery`

as following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#btnSubmit').click(function(){

        // set urls
        var url1 = 'http://php.url.com',
            url2 = 'http://jsp.url.com';

        // prepare data
        var data = {
            'field1' : 'val1',
            'field2' : 2
        }

        // prepare callback (one callback for both requests)
        var callback = function(data) {
            console.log('request ended with data: ' + data);
        }

        // send post requests to both servers with the same data payload
        $.post(url1, data, callback);
        $.post(url2, data, callback);
    });
});
</script>

<input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
```

with this approach, click on button will send 2 async post requests, one to each server endpoint you set.

hope that helps.

Comment: Please see my edit, I've made a mistake in my original description.

Answer (score 0):

you don't post to a "javascript file".  javascript needs to be hosted in html.  So I don't know if you need to INCLUDE the js file in your html file, and call a function, or if you actually meant post to another hmtl file on another server.

to specifically answer, you can make 2 forms and submit each one of them.

with jquery you can create a form dynamically and submit it. use post as the method, not get.

```
$('<form>', {
    "id": "getInvoiceImage",
    "html": '<input type="text" id="componentInvoicId" name="componentInvoicId" value="' + componentInvoiceId + '" />',
    "action": window.siteRoot + 'ComponentInvoice/GetInvoiceImage/'
}).appendTo(document.body).submit();
```

Comment: Please see my edit, I've made a mistake in my original description.

Comment: well, you can use a form to send data to a jsp right?  so you still need to submit 2 separate forms.  so as Gal V said, you can do onclick and create a new form with jquery, and submit it to the jsp, then it will do the regular submit to the php

Comment: Alright, that sounds good. I'll try to implement that, and then I'll get back to you.

Comment: I'm not sure my form is quite right. Can you check this out and tell me if it looks ok please? http://pastebin.com/yZdaggPE